# Bash regex evaluation failure

Tags: regex, bash, husky

I have the following regex pattern I'd like to use to validate git commit messages. `(((CMS-)|(UIDEV-)|(CONTENT-)|(RPT-))[0-9]+\\s-\\s)|(NOTICKET- )`

However when I have a sample message of `CMS-7120 - test commit message`, the regex match fails and enter the `if` condition. I used to have `\\d+` but realized that wasn't POSIX compliant and changed it above but unsure why I'm not getting a match. Tested it on regex101 and I do get a match there. Any thoughts on what is wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

pattern="(((CMS-)|(UIDEV-)|(CONTENT-)|(RPT-))[0-9]+\\s-\\s)|(NOTICKET- )"
message="$(cat $1)"

if [[ !($message =~ $pattern) ]]; then
    echo "bad commit message"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `\s` is a PCRE extension. Bash only guarantees support for ERE regex syntax (extensions beyond that are specific to the libc it was compiled against, thus to your operating system).

Comment: Use `[[:space:]]` instead.

Comment: Also, you can't reliably use `sh` in your shebang line with bash-only syntax. Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, not `#!/usr/bin/env sh`.

Comment: And spaces are important. `if ! [[ $message =~ $pattern ]]` is better practice, or if you _must_ have the parens, `if [[ ! ( $message =~ $pattern ) ]]`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/MYRrjk showing code working after being modified as described above.

Comment: ...and btw, consider `message=$(<"$1")` to avoid the overhead of starting `cat`.

Comment: (and think about using single-quotes instead of double-quotes by default -- with single quotes you don't need to double up your backslashes; and more generally, because there's less processing inside them, using them lets a reader know that your substring is literal).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. That solved it and I learned more about bash.